eliminating separation lines between rows of table
I simply want to create a full-page-width single-column table with black background.
But somehow there is this white line between rows (wme1).
I tried to create newline instead of new row, the white line disappears but it messes up  the alignment. (mwe2)
Any solution for this?

mwe1
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}>{\color{white}}p{1\textwidth}|}
           \cellcolor{black} \tiny First Argument \\ \hline
           \cellcolor{black} Second long Argument\\ \hline
           \cellcolor{black} \Large Third Argument\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

mwe2
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}>{\color{white}}p{1\textwidth}|}
           \cellcolor{black} \tiny First Argument \\ \hline
           \cellcolor{black} Second long Argument\\ \hline
           \cellcolor{black} \Large Third Argument \newline \normalsize Fourth Argument\\ \hline
\end{tabular}


This isn't really how a table is supposed to be used (solid color and one column), so you're having problems.  Why are you wanting to do this?

@Teepeemm, basically I want to create a white text with black background that spans the whole page width. I am open to any other possibility other than table environment.

If you do not want to see a horizontal line (\hline), do not use it. A tabular without lines and one (1) single cell with \cellcolor{black}\centering \color{white} text \par more text \par  ...and   is enough. Or use a  minipage in a \colorbox, or the  tcolorbox package (overkill for this simple task). In any case, this avoid the  constraints of  tabular rows. BTW, this is to make a  front page or so?.  In this case search "titlepage."
